# how to get Android_Accelerated_x86 emulator?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android

Emulator in the image below is one of the fastest emulator in xamarin. I have 2 computers and 1 of them has this emulator somehow installed. whatever I tried and I searched all over, I cant find out how to install this emulator on my other computer. Does anybody know how do I get this emulator. something similar described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/) but it is not the same at all.

I have already api level 23 and intel atom(x86) for this api level installed

[image]

I have installed extras in android sdk manager as below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of getting an x86 enabled emulator.

First is by installing the Intel HAXM emulator. To do so open Xamarin Studio click on tools and open SDK Manager. In the Extras folder you will see an entry Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator.

An even simple solution is to install Android Studio and during the installation set the SDK path to the one configured inside Xamarin Studio. The benefit is, that you can use Android Studio for stuff like memory monitoring, CPU usage and such as well as getting a better designer for your layouts.

I described it for Xamarin Studio but the steps basically applies to Visual Studio as well.

Comment: I have installed the HAXM emulator (see my edited post). But although I dont get that emulator. Only difference between my 2 computers is the one has this emulator has also VS 2017RC installed. I am thinking if MS included this emulator with VS 2017RC. I will consider your advise regarding installing Android Studio as well.

Comment: I am not aware off that VS 2017 RC ships a new android emulator version.

Comment: I just found the solution. please see my answer below. :) btw thanks again for the Android Studio suggestion. It has also really a lot of benefits

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question. Just for anyone who will have same interest here is the answer. I dislike xamarin android emulators in general. I used to test my app using real device rather. Advantages were,

- I didnt need any virtualization whatever hassle to be installed like hyper v
- They occupy a lot of space on my ssd drive

but this emulator is beautiful, fast and light. It occupies only around 700mb. I highly recommend this emulator to anyone.

It comes with VS 2017 RC installation but you dont need to install VS 2017. It is also working with VS 2015. Just download the VS 2017 installer and choose the emulator only from the list.

PS, I guess most of the xamarin presentations made by microsoft and xamarin is with this emulator :)

[image]

Comment: This is the one that ships with Android Studio. ;-)

Comment: @tequilaslammer I installed Android Studio but in the virtual devices list, i cant see it. What could be the reason?